Proper connection of different ground zones / Isolation
I am currently working on a board that has some different IO options such as Ethernet with discrete magnetics, RS232 and USB2.0.
I do struggle with connecting the different ground regions properly to each other. Per my understanding of this post all ground regions shall be interconnected with each other via the metal chassis.
Currently all my mounting holes are connecting the GND zone they are placed in to the chassis. This should allow for many short GND interconnections over the chassis without having high currents running over the PCB.
I have also already placed a mounting hole close to the power input to the board from the PSU. The PSU (Meanwell EPS-45-5) also connects via the mounting screws to the chassis (AC and DC side, Datasheet page 2). The incoming AC Earth is also terminated to the chassis.


The shields of all connectors are separately connected to the chassis via dedicated GNDCHASSIS planes.
Ethernet
I have kept the area for the signals between the magnetics and the RJ45 Port clear from any ground plane as recommended by most magnetic datasheets.
Are the ground connections of the Bob-Smith-Termination capacitors to the GNDCHASSIS plane correct?
Is it sufficient to only connect two of the 6 chassis connectors to the GNDCHASSIS plane (due to space restrictions)? I verified, that they are all part of the same bent piece of metal.
RS232
The RS232 IO port is separated for isolation and has an additional GNDISO plane for the digital signals processed in that region (RS232-UART Transceivers). The UART signals are than passed over the digital isolators placed across the isolation gap. Does the GNDISO plane also need a connection to the chassis?
Power is passed over the isolation gap via an isolated DC-DC converter.
USB
The shield of the connector is again directly connected to the enclosure via a GNDCHASSIS plane and a mounting screw. Same question here as for the RJ45 connector: Is it sufficient to connect only two of the four mounting points of the connector to the CHASSISGND if they are part of the same piece of metal?
I have connected the GND of the TVS-Diode to the GNDCHASSIS plane to direct and ESD currents away from my digital ground plane. Is this correct? The GND-Pin of the USB-connector is directly connected to my GNDD digital ground plane.
Please let me know your thoughts about my current approach to connecting the different ground zones and proper isolation and ESD handling of the in- and outgoing connections.

Thanks for the hint. The RS232 will only communicate with devices which are within a range of about two metres. It can occur, that the device attached via the RS232 interface is powered by a generator while the board itself is powered from a regular wall socket. Is the isolation in that case still negligible?

We have to assume, that the generator is properly grounded and the electrical system available from the wall socket is also properly grounded. In this case there shouldn't be any requirements for proper isolation if I understand you correctly?

Okay, thanks for the hint.
If I wanted to keep the isolation as the components are only a few extra cents in respect to the whole project, should I also tie the GNDISO plane to the chassis?

Basically, all your FG nodes go separately to metal chassis and GNDD too, so they are galvanically anyway connected together. I get that you want to return them separately to common star ground point, but on the other hand, they all could just as well be connected  together on the PCB as well, in addition to being bolted to chassis from the mounting holes.
Basically, the problem is, if there is ESD, and it jumps to chassis from connector shells, where would ESD return through chassis, except to other connector shells and also back to DGND at power connector, but there are multiple routes for that, so it can flow through chassis and also through PCB.
For Ethernet, it looks correct. Connector shield to FG, Bob Smith caps to FG, and the PHY side CT caps to PHY GND.
For USB, that looks a bit odd. That's a host side connector, so in general, the connector shell and DGND are tied together. And they are but only via chassis. The ESD protection would never be to connector shell, as you need to protect data lines in relation to DGND where some USB chip is. The routing is also asymmetrical, usually you run data wires on top of ground plane with 90 ohm differential impedance. That looks like trouble.
For RS-232, sure the data pins are isolated, but connector shell is tied to chassis FG. The data and ground pins in the connector are floating isolated at no potential. The ISOGND likely wiggles at Recom module switching frequency 50 kHz, has too little load to run at stable 5V instead of overvoltage, and has no suggested EMI filter and Common Mode capacitors to prevent it from just emitting 50 kHz. Usually you need some nF from ISOGND to DGND over the Recom grounds. Anyway, the DE-9 GND pin 5 not being at same potential as connector shell may be a problem. It might be best to not isolate and use same DC potential on the RS-232 interface - unless you need to isolate, then isolate the DE-9 shell too to isolated GND.

Do I understand you correctly, that the approach of creating multiple connection points from GNDCHASSIS and GNDD to the chassis itself is preferred to provide more paths for ESD currents?
Differential routing for USB and GND plane under signals is mandatory and only left out in the pictures above as this is a demo schematic for this post. USB Shield and signal GND will be connected to GNDD directly. ESD protection diodes ground will be connected to GNDD.

RS232: The equipment which will be connected is unknown to us. Therefor I would prefer full isolation. I have checked the datasheet of the power transformer which recommends a 270pF/2kV cap across GNDISO and GNDD to maintain galvanic isolation but provide a path for HF-components. A load resistor will be added as recommended by the datasheet to keep the transformer in a stable region.
What would you recommend for EMI-Filter and common mode capcitors in the fully isolated case?
The metal chassis should be kept far enough away from the connector, to avoid a connection there, correct?
